# how to make mysql columns value depend on other columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

Stack:
Laravel v8, MySQL.

I working on a payroll system with Laravel.

I want the value of some columns to update if another column it depends on changes.

For example, if the Number of working days changes on the payrolls table, then the salary and other columns that depends on 'Number of working days' column should re-calculate based on the new value and save to the database.

How do I go about this?
Are there any Laravel packages that handles this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `laravel` model, there are [`events`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events) you could use for example if the user `first_name` or `last_name` is updated I want to update the `full_name` too like this

```php
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::updating(function ($user) {
            if($user->isDirty('first_name') || $user->isDirty('last_name')){
                 $user->full_name = $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is all the `events` you could listen for: `retrieved`, `creating`, `created`, `updating`, `updated`, `saving`, `saved`, `deleting`, `deleted`, `trashed`, `forceDeleted`, `restoring`, `restored`, and `replicating`

Comment: Do I need to call the save method again?

Comment: No, there is no need

Comment: If it rely helps, you could accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it myself, but it seems like you could solve this with a MYSQL Trigger or event:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html